# How long PloS One "Decision in Process" status remain?

Tags: paper-submission, journal-workflow

Anybody who has published in Plos One, can you tell me how long did the manuscript status take to change from "Decision in Process" to accepted or to receive the letter of acceptance? And how long did it take to publish after acceptance? Will be a great help. My manuscript status is stucked at " Decision in process" for more than 3 weeks now and the editor and the journal office says the editor has submitted the decision but doesnt say why such a delay.

Comment: 3 weeks is not a very big duration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of the "Decision in Process" phase at PLoS ONE can range widely, taking anywhere from a few days to several weeks. If your manuscript has been in this stage for over three weeks, it's natural to feel a bit on edge. Delays can occur, especially during busy times or when complex issues arise. The journal office's message suggests that your decision letter should be on its way shortly. Once accepted, articles typically take a few more weeks to be published. If there's no change soon, it might be worth giving the editor or journal office another nudge. Patience is key during this process. Best of luck with your manuscript, mate!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It has been more than one month and now nobody in the journal responds to me nor I got the decision yet. I don't know what to do. Is this normal with PLOS ONE ? Does it take this long for them to give a decision?